# Nested while statements only running inner while SQL

Tags: sql, loops, while-loop

I am trying to create a table with the following rows:

| Date | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 01/01/2021 | 1.0 |
| 01/02/2021 | 0.5 |
| 01/02/2021 | 0.5 |
| 01/03/2021 | 0.33 |
| 01/03/2021 | 0.33 |
| 01/03/2021 | 0.33 |
| 01/04/2021 | 0.25 |
| 01/04/2021 | 0.25 |
| 01/04/2021 | 0.25 |
| 01/04/2021 | 0.25 |

My attempt below only appears to run the inner statement, the outer statement is redundant but when I run the outer statement on its own, it returns all of the end date combinations.

I am sure I am missing something very simple.

Thanks in advance.

```
SET DATEFORMAT dmy;

SET @start   = '01/09/2021'
SET @end     = '01/09/2025'
SET @counter = 1
    
WHILE (@end> @start)
BEGIN
    
    WHILE (@counter < DATEDIFF(m,@start,@end))
    BEGIN

        INSERT INTO #timerevert (mon,frac)
        VALUES( @end, 1 / (datediff(m,@start,@end)*1.0) )
    
    SET @counter = @counter + 1
    
    END

    SET @end = dateadd(mm,-1,@end)

END
```

Comment: Protip: you don't need a `WHILE` loop, nor `#temporary` tables. Instead, try to think about how you can describe the data using set-theoretical operations (hint: your `Value` is clearly a function of `Date`).

Comment: It uses a SET DATEFORMAT dmy; at the start, sorry, this is isnt the full query which creates the table and declares variables.

Comment: This is a simple set-based query, very easy if you have a *numbers/tally table* to hand.

Comment: @Stu I would have thought a self-referential CTE would be better for generating rows _ex nihilo_.

Comment: To confirm, you want 1 row for `2021-01-01`, 2 rows for `2021-01-02`, 3 rows for `2021-01-03`, 4 rows for `2021-01-04`, through to 365 rows for `2021-12-31`? That would be **66,795 rows** in total for 2021 - but you want to go all the way to 2025... are you sure that's what you want? I saw your `@start` variable is `2021-09-01` and not `2021-01-01`, so I'm not sure what you **really** want...

Comment: @Dai of course a recursive CTE will work just fine, I'd choose a tally table if I had one though especially if it's a repeating task.

Answer (score 0):

(I was wrong in my comments when I claimed you didn't need a `WHILE` loop. While *technically* it's very possible to generate rows *ex nihilo* using a CTE or similar, unfortunately T-SQL does not make that a "better" approach: for example, CTEs have a recursion limit which this type of query would very quickly hit).

My approach below splits the problem into 2 parts:

1. The first part generates a simple date-range table variable, which includes an `n int` column, which is simply the *number-of-days-since-`2021-01-01`* - which also additionally serves as the value for how many repeated rows you want (as you want the same row repeated `n` times, where `n` is the *number-of-days-since-`2021-01-01`*.
2. Then the simple flat list of dates is `CROSS APPLY`-d to itself to then generate the additional rows for the *number-of-days-since-`2021-01-01`*.

---

**Warning:** For the date range `2021-01-01` to `2025-09-01` this generates **1,452,660 rows** and took 5 seconds to run on my 6-year-old LAN dev server (some low-end Xeon chip from 2013).

```
DECLARE @dates TABLE (
    n int  NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    d date NOT NULL 
);

-- Part 1:
BEGIN
    DECLARE @start date = '2021-01-01';
    DECLARE @end   date = '2025-09-01';
    DECLARE @i     date = @start;
    
    WHILE @i < @end
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @dates ( d ) VALUES ( @i );
        SET @i = DATEADD( day, 1, @i );
    END;
    
END;

-- Part 2:
SELECT
    dt.n,
    dt.d AS [Date],
    dtn.dateSubRowNumber,
    ( 1.0 / dt.n ) AS [Value]
FROM
    @dates AS dt
    CROSS APPLY
    (
        SELECT
            TOP ( dt.n )
            dti.n AS dateSubRowNumber,
            dti.d
        FROM
            @dates AS dti
        ORDER BY
            dti.n
    ) AS dtn;
```

Comment-out the outer `dt.n` and dtn.dateSubRowNumber` columns to get the exact same output as your sample expected output.

Output:

[image]